# Termite terminal color mess

Tags: terminal, colors, termite

I am trying to tweak colors for Termite, but instead of the expected I'm getting a total mess (colors differs from my `~/.config/termite/config`. In screenshot numbers should be gray, text yellow and etc.)

Also, can I set Vim's colorscheme different from terminal? 
[image]

PS. I don't think this is a duplicate, because the issue seems to be due to the terminal.  Vim is just an unrelated point.

It really seems like it's a Termite internal problem, because one can get it only through compiling sources. It seems like no one really tested it on Ubuntu.

Comment: That looks like Vim's `:colo elflord` for me, the colorscheme.  What is the output of `:colo` in your Vim?

Comment: :colo gives `default`